# Error returning char* in c++ function

Tags: c++, string, buffer, string-literals

I have this function:

```
char* return_string(){
    char buffer[] = "Hi world!";
    return buffer;
}

bool test08()
{
    char compare[] = "Hi world!";
    int result = strcmp(compare,return_string());
if (result == 0) return true;
return false;
}
int main()
{
if(test08) printf("\nTRUE");
else printf("\nFALSE");
}
```

Why this code run in [c++ Shell](http://cpp.sh/) and it doesn't in codeblocks v. 13.12 (Segmentation fault); it'll work if i change my `char buffer[]=` declaration to `char *buffer=;` i'm a beginner at C++ (easy to know) so please be clear...

Comment: It's undefined behaviour.You are returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: Don't spam tags of unrelated languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the function `return_string` the following way

```
const char* return_string(){
    const char *buffer = "Hi world!";
    return buffer;
}
```

The problem with the original function implementation is that the array `buffer` is a local array of the function with the automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function.

In the modified function there is used a string literal that has static storage duration. So you may return a pointer to the first character of the string literal.

The function `test08` can be written simpler

```
bool test08()
{
    char compare[] = "Hi world!";
    return strcmp( compare, return_string() ) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
char* return_string(){
    char buffer[] = "Hi world!";
    return buffer;
}
```

copies the string "Hi world!" into the local variable `buffer` and then returns that local variable - this results in undefined behaviour if you try to use that return value, because the buffer is discarded on function exit.

This:

```
   char* return_string(){
       char *buffer = "Hi world!";
        return buffer;
   }
```

would actually be OK, though probably not what you want. You would be returning the address of the start of a string literal (stored in a mysterious place, re the standard), which is OK.In C++, you would have problems with const.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `return_string` is returning pointer to a local variable `buffer` that is defined only in the scope of `return_string`. When the function returns, you return the address of where `buffer` used to be stored while the value stored in that address is no longer valid.
Well, if you insist on returning a pointer to character, you can dynamically allocate "Hello World" and **remember to free it later**:

```
char * return_string() {
    char local_var[] = "hello world";
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(local_var));
    strcpy(buffer, local_var); // we know that buffer is big enough to hold local_var
    return buffer;
}
```

Since the memory in which "hello world" is stored is not local to the function, it won't be released when the function exits.

Another (better) solution is to pass a statically allocated `buffer` (hopefully large enough to hold your value) to `return_string` and modify its content there.

```
void return_string(char *buffer, size_t buffer_size) {
    strncpy(buffer, "hello world", buffer_size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to a buffer but the buffer variable gets destroyed after the function returns.

You need to make your buffer variable static.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer at all, but still...
I've tried on CodeBlocks 16.01 (mingw) and everything works smoothly.
So a quick suggestion, always try working with the upgraded versions of any software, especially if you still in learning process.

Comment: This is a typical case of "undefined behavior" *accidentally* working even though the code is wrong, making it much harder to identify the bug.

Comment: C++ does not work this way.  Just because it seems to work does not mean the code is "ok".  Returning the address of a local variable is undefined behavior, regardless of what that behavior may be.  It could work, it could fail, it could fail if compiled with different options, it may work today, fail tomorrow, etc.